# Setting up .htaccess with apache and laravel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

This seems to have been asked hundreds of times, and I read it and tried different things. Nothing seems to work, so after reading about 5 google pages about this I gave up and I want to see if anyone can give me an answer.

I want to remove the `/public` from my URL

I'm using an **apache 2.4 server on windows**. I just installed laravel.

I made sure the rewrite module is on in apache (php's `get_apache_modules()` shows it) and now I'm trying to write the `.htaccess` - and I can't understand how it works.
I don't want to change anything in my apache configurations (I'm using this machine to develop multiple apps)

my current `.htaccess` files are :
in the app route directory

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
```

and in the public folder

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /texteditor/public/index.php [L]
```

Right now localhost/texteditor/ - and anything after it that isn't public/ gives me 404

Also can anyone recommend an easy .htaccess tutorial for dummies?

Comment: you should change the DocumentRoot in your apache config file (thus, not in the .htaccess) to point to the public folder, rather than to the folder above.

Comment: I don't want to change the apache document root. I have other apps running on the same server. Unless there is a way to change the root for just this one folder?

Comment: The usual solution is to use virtual hosts: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/

Comment: no other way? it did seem like something htaccess would take care of no?

Comment: I don't think so. Actually, the only way would be to move Laravel in the folder above, which may cause some side-effects on other apps 404s. Use vhosts.

Comment: I got one part resolved. I don't need the index.php anymore - did it by putting full path in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this thing by doing following and working fine.
Please do this if it is helpful to you.

1. Move `public/index.php` to `www/texteditor/index.php`.
2. also Move `public/.htaccess` to `www/texteditor/.htaccess`.

then you can do it.

Please replace your app root directory's `.htaccess` with `public/.htaccess`.